# How string allocates the memory in heap?

Tags: c#, vb.net, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am confused in memory allocation while creating object of String class. I have created a sample application that demonstrates how much memory being allocated when the string object is declared. Then I have tried to increase the length of string to see the difference total consumed memory in heap.

My testing code is here

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long l1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    long l2 = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(l1.ToString());

    myFunc();

    l2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine(l2.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Difference : {0}", (l2-l1)));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void myFunc()
{
    String str = new String('a', 1);
}
```

the output comes when i execute this code:

```
775596 //Memory at startup
816556 //After executing function
Difference : 40960
```

The above output is same for string length 0 to 2727. for example even i create the object of string with the length of 2727 the out comes same as above.

```
String str = new String('a', 2727);
```

But, when i increase one more in the value and create a string for 2728 the output comes different.

```
775596 //Memory at startup
822780 //After executing function
Difference : 47184
```

I have also tried it in VB.Net console application. In the VB.Net output comes same for 0 to 797 length of string. but, it gets changed when i increase the value to 798.

*I don't know how it allocates the memory according to length of string?*

The character array(string) says it has 2727 items with 97 byte(for character 'a'). I thought it multiplies the value with the character byte. I know the character type has fixed length of 256 bytes. but, i was just wondering why it happens? So, I have also tried to change the character from 'a' to 'z'. but, the result was same as expected.

Can anyone describe it clearly how the memory gets allocated when any string or other class object is declared?

Comment: You can always check the source code. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you have actually allocated 2 strings between your memory checks, not just one. `Console.WriteLine(l1.ToString());` is also allocating a string.

Comment: Remember, characters are not bytes! 1 character = 2 bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is with your method of research.

```
int[] lengths = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 };
string[] strs = new string[lengths.Length];
long[] deltaMemory = new long[lengths.Length];

// We preload the functions we will use
var str0 = new string('A', 1);
var length0 = str0.Length;
long totalMemory0 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
long lastTotalMemory = totalMemory0;

for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
{
    strs[i] = new string((char)('A' + i), lengths[i]);
    long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    deltaMemory[i] = totalMemory - lastTotalMemory - lengths[i] * 2;
    lastTotalMemory = totalMemory;
}

Console.WriteLine("IntPtr.Size: {0}", IntPtr.Size);
for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("For size: {0}, extra memory: {1}", strs[i].Length, deltaMemory[i]);
}
```

You have to remember various things:

- Don't allocate memory in any way other than the one you are measuring
- Remember that the first time a method is called it must be JITted. I'll say that this operation eats memory. Pre-call once all the methods you'll use
- A `String` in .NET is UTF-16, so each character 2 two bytes (`lengthts[i] * 2`)
- There is surely some rounding around because memory is allocated in fixed chunks, of size connected to the size of `IntPtr` (so depending if you are working at 32 or 64 bits)

The result:

```
IntPtr.Size: 8
For size: 1, extra memory: 30
For size: 2, extra memory: 28
For size: 3, extra memory: 26
For size: 4, extra memory: 32
For size: 5, extra memory: 30
For size: 6, extra memory: 28
For size: 7, extra memory: 26
For size: 8, extra memory: 32
For size: 9, extra memory: 30
For size: 10, extra memory: 28
For size: 11, extra memory: 26
For size: 12, extra memory: 32
For size: 13, extra memory: 30
For size: 14, extra memory: 28
For size: 15, extra memory: 26
For size: 16, extra memory: 32
For size: 17, extra memory: 30
For size: 18, extra memory: 28
For size: 19, extra memory: 26
For size: 20, extra memory: 32
For size: 21, extra memory: 30
For size: 22, extra memory: 28
For size: 23, extra memory: 26
For size: 24, extra memory: 32
For size: 25, extra memory: 30
For size: 26, extra memory: 28
For size: 27, extra memory: 26
For size: 28, extra memory: 32
For size: 29, extra memory: 30
For size: 30, extra memory: 28
For size: 31, extra memory: 26
For size: 32, extra memory: 32
For size: 64, extra memory: 32
For size: 128, extra memory: 32
For size: 256, extra memory: 32
For size: 512, extra memory: 32
For size: 1024, extra memory: 32
For size: 2048, extra memory: 32
For size: 4096, extra memory: 32
```

So each string has (at 64 bits) an extra 26-32 bytes allocated. Mmmh... I see that Skeet even wrote a blog post on memory allocation: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated

In other words, the value returned by this method is *not* a precise accounting of all of the bytes actually allocated.

I don't know the exact implementation of that method, but it wouldn't surprise me to find that there is some low-priority process that is involved that is monitoring a high-water mark in the heap in order to provide the value in question. (As an aside, it is interestingly coincidental to me that your first difference works out to 2^12 * 10).

Note that this imprecision in the value returned really doesn't tell you anything about "how the memory gets allocated". I'm not really sure if your question really is just "why doesn't this value change the way I expected it to", or if you're looking for a more detailed explanation of how objects in general are allocated in .NET.

But if you want to know more about the latter, there are actually some pretty good articles, including this pair on MSDN by Jeffrey Richter:

- [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection Part 2: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)

They are a bit old, and don't cover some new features in the GC, but the basics haven't really changed AFAIK, and those articles are IMHO timeless.

The short version is that, for the `string` type since it is immutable, the buffer for the string can be allocated directly based on the length of the string (note that this is different than e.g. a class like `List<T>` or `StringBuilder`, which have more elaborate data structures, and so wind up exercising the .NET memory manager in more complicated ways).

And because of the way the .NET memory manager works, a new allocation of an object is simply a matter of looking at the pointer to the current end of the allocation portion of the heap, using that for the new object, and moving the pointer the number of bytes you've allocated.

(The `string` type is a pretty special type in .NET, as it gets native code support and special handling for its internal buffer, but the basic idea of being allocated on the heap still applies).

Again, none of this does anything to explain the behavior you're seeing. But it is an answer to the broader question of how memory allocations happen.

Back to the question of the `GC.GetTotalMemory()` method, I did find this interesting discussion from the now-defunct newsgroup about .NET, archived at PC Review's web site (and probably elsewhere, but this is where I found it):
[What does GC.GetTotalMemory really tell us?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/what-does-gc-gettotalmemory-really-tell-us.1229326/). The discussion meanders a bit, and I don't think it really addresses head-on the question you're asking. But you might find it an interesting read anyway.